# Hibernate - force inner join between parent and subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, inheritance, inner-join

I have a parent class `Party` and a subclass `LiveParty` along with others (see below) and this is always a one to one relationship in the database.  Whenever I use the Criteria API it does a Left Outer Join between the two. I want to force an Inner Join between the parent and child as this affects performance for some queries but can't find a way to do this in the documentation, can anyone suggest a way?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Party", schema = "dbo")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Party{
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LiveParty", schema = "dbo")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "partyId")
public class LiveParty extends Party {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I use the Criteria API it does a Left Outer Join between the two.

That's indeed what you'll get when using a `JOINED` strategy, Hibernate will perform an outer join on **all** the tables corresponding to descendants of a given node of the inheritance tree in order to deduce and return the actual type for a given row (see [this great previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530657/hibernate-inheritance-strategy-and-why/1533041#1533041) by ChssPly76 for details).

In other words, I don't *think* you can force Hibernate to use an inner join, at least not without changing the mapping (using a secondary table or a `OneToOne` relation, I'm not sure what your constraints are exactly).

#### Related questions

- [Hibernate Inheritance Strategy and Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530657/hibernate-inheritance-strategy-and-why/1533041#1533041)
- [How does the JPA handle partial, non-disjoint inheritance (using InheritanceType.JOINED in class-per-table scenario) along with EntityManager.find()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149920/how-does-the-jpa-handle-partial-non-disjoint-inheritance-using-inheritancetype/4154064#4154064)